# How to export selected rows from Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have created a datagridveiw to display access database. I need to create a export function from datagrideview to MS Excel. Below are my coding to export all data from datagrideview to MS Excel.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        Button3.Text = "Please Wait..."
        Button3.Enabled = False

        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Document (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
            Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer

            xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

            For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
                For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                    For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
                    Next
                Next
            Next

            xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
            xlWorkBook.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()

            releaseObject(xlApp)
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

            MsgBox("Successfully saved" & vbCrLf & "File are saved at : " & SaveFileDialog1.FileName, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")

            Button3.Text = "Export To MS Excel"
            Button3.Enabled = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to save !!!", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return
    End Try
```

How i can export only selected data rows from Datagrideview to MS Excel with the use of checkboxes?

Comment: `If DataGridView.Rows(i).Selected Then`

Comment: `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows`.  Seems the obvious choice.

Comment: Does the datagridview have a column of checkboxes? If not, add one. If so use it to see if there is a check in the box.

Comment: Please try copy your selected row and paste to your excel, the clue are to Assign YourGrid.ClipboardCopyMode, perform Clipboard.SetDataObject of your selected rows and at the last to paste the clipboard data to excel sheet

Comment: @John 
@LarsTech
@jmcilhinney
 I added checkbox column to gridview with below coding,

`Dim checkBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColum()
checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = '' ''
checkBoxColumn.Width = 30
checkBoxColumn.Name = ''checkBoxColumn''
DataGridView1.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn`


Can you Please type exact code to replace my coding to save only selected rows ?